# stop data-bind event in click method

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I have a checkbox that causes validation on a textbox and is also data-bind to an viewmodel.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JanGous/U4eJA/).

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: viewitems">Checkbox</input>
```

I want the the checkbox not to data-bind when the click event returns a false value.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't say that I particularly understand the question, and your jsFiddle doesn't help. Why do you not want the observable bound to the checkbox if the click function returns false?

Comment: The checkbox causes validation on the textbox. If the validation returns false the bind event for should not happen. Only when the validation event returns true the bind should happen

Comment: What I meant was, why do you want to do this? It seems like a bit of a strange thing to do, so I'm wondering if this is your attempt to get round another problem you have with the code. If it is, then maybe we can come up with a better way of getting round that problem.

Comment: My app has an datetimepicker and under that has a checkbox that opens some more options bases on the datetimepicker's value.when the users selects the checkbox before the date has been selected the validation then gets fired to warn the user that the date has not been selected. But at the moment the validation gets fired off correctly but the options also show with out the date being selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just set the value of your observable in your click method?

```
$('#checkbox1').click(function ()
{
    if (!$('#textbox1').valid())
    {
        viewitems(false)
        alert("Please enter value");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        viewitems(true)
    }
});
```

Comment: Not working for me. I just don't want to bind the value when it's false.

Comment: I really don't think that you can do that, and even if there is some way to do it, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JanGous Ok, try this answer then.